# How to convert a polygon to a polyline using the sf package in R?

Tags: r, polygon, sf

I have some simple polygons that I would like to convert to polylines using the `sf` package in R. I have found `st_polygonize` to convert polylines to polygons but I cannot but the reserve operation. Some documentation suggested that `st_segmentize` would work but I haven't found it useful.

Comment: Hang on, do you want polygon to polyline or polyline to polygon? Your title says one, your first line says the other, then you say polylines to polygons...

Comment: I made a mistake in the title. Thanks for your answer to my question in the text! It's much simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert a simple polygon `P` (that defines an area) to a line `L` use:

```
L = st_cast(P,"LINESTRING")
```

eg using `pl` from `example(st_polygon)`:

```
> st_polygon(pl)
POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))
> st_cast(st_polygon(pl),"LINESTRING")
LINESTRING (0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)
```